# Spark Job using old application resources and jar

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I am new to spark . Trying to run spark job with client mode and it works well if I use the same path for jar and other resource files. After killing the running application using Yarn command and if spark job is resubmitted with updated jar and file locations, job still uses my old path. After reboot of system , spark job takes new path. Spark-submit command

```
spark-submit \
    --class export.streaming.DataExportStreaming \
    --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/postgresql-9.4.1209.jar \
    --driver-class-path /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/postgresql-9.4.1209.jar  \
    --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/postgresql-9.4.1209.jar \
    --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/postgresql-9.4.1209.jar \
    --master yarn --deploy-mode client \
    --files /usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_selfservice_session_daily.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_selfservice_session_device.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_selfservice_session_workflow.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_selfservice_session_workflow_step.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_session_assignment.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_session_daily.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_session_device.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_session_queue.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_session_workflow.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_session_workflow_step.sql,/usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/rollup_user_login_session.sql /usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/lib/data-export-assembly-52.0.2-1.jar /usr/lib/firebet-spark/52.0.2-1/data-export/resources/application.conf
```

How to fix this problem ?
Is spark-submit command is correct ?
Which deployment mode is better client or cluster in production ?

Comment: After searching a lot in google I found that checkpoint directory is the root cause for this issue. Without removing existing checkpoint directory if code is upgraded to new one and redeployed then spark uses the old context stored in checkpoint directory. For more detail http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#how-to-configure-checkpointing   ,  http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/05/07/spark-kafka-achieving-zero-data-loss.html  and a possible hack http://why-not-learn-something.blogspot.in/2016/08/upgrading-running-spark-streaming.html